# Understanding initializing an empty dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I really do not understand how there was the command (if "entry" in langs_count) is possible when the dictionary was initialized to be empty, so what is inside the dictionary and how did it get there? I'm really confused

`

```
import pandas as pd

# Import Twitter data as DataFrame: df
df = pd.read_csv("tweets.csv")

# Initialize an empty dictionary: langs_count
langs_count = {}

# Extract column from DataFrame: col
col = df['lang']

# Iterate over lang column in DataFrame
for entry in col:

    # If the language is in langs_count, add 1 
    if entry in langs_count.keys():
        langs_count[entry]+=1
    # Else add the language to langs_count, set the value to 1
    else:
        langs_count[entry]=1

# Print the populated dictionary
print(langs_count)
```

`

Comment: Your problem is far from clear: please state precisely what happens, what you expected, etc.

Comment: You just provide code but don't tell what happens.

Comment: Initially the dictionary is empty so the `else` branch is followed. A new key with the value represented by `entry` is added to the dictionary and is assigned the value of 1. Whenever a value for entry is encountered that is not present in the dictionary keys the same process is followed.

Comment: The code is in a loop. Items with the same key may be added after a few passes through the loop.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @0x0fba the code was supposed to extract the language column from a data frame named df and then the dictionary was initialized to be empty. There is a for loop in the code to iterate over the "lang" column that was extracted. So now my question goes thus: how is the code asking if an item is in the langs_count dictionary when the dictionary was initialized to be empty

Comment: @Swifty This is not my code so I'm trying to understand it but the code was supposed to extract a column "lang" from a data frame "df" and then iterate over that column, what brought my question here is the fact that I do not understand how  the code went thus: "if entry in langs_count" I'm quite confused because the langs_count dictionary was initialized to be empty but the code asks the if statement as if the dictionary was filled with the entries in the column extracted.

Comment: I'm not sure that it will help but I understand that the only purpose of the code is to create the dictionary. Just by 1) adding the lang and init the counter to 1 if not yet in the dict, 2) incrementing the counter is already in the dict.
I wonder why it's done in pure Python. There are chances that a more efficient solution exists to perform that computation directly with pandas.

Comment: @0x0fba omg, something you said in your comment just made it click and I think I now have a grasp of it and you are also right when you said there's a better solution in pandas, Dan Nagle in the answers section just provided an answer of that using the "groupby" function. Thank you so much for your time and comment, it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the count functionality using `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd

# Import Twitter data as DataFrame: df
df = pd.read_csv("tweets.csv")

# Populate dictionary with count of occurrences in 'lang' column
langs_count = dict(df.groupby(['lang']).size())

# Print the populated dictionary
print(langs_count)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and I would like to ask if this code would give the exact same results with the one I posted earlier

Comment: Provided the data is valid then both methods should produce the same end result. As the size of the data grows, groupby would be the faster method.